# How can I send multiple values to a powershell function

Tags: powershell, scripting

Here is a script I used to check status of my URL whether it is working or not. I need to write a script in such a way that it accepts all the URLs present in a text file which is placed in local drive and displays their information.

```
[string] $url = 'http://mywebsite.net'
function CheckForStatus($url) {
try {
    [net.httpWebRequest] $req = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
    $req.Method = "HEAD"
    [net.httpWebResponse] $res = $req.getResponse()
    if ($res.StatusCode -eq "200") {
        write-host "`nSite $url is up (Return code: $($res.StatusCode) - 
$([int] $res.StatusCode))`n" -ForegroundColor green 
    }
    else {
       write-host "`nSite $url is not available (Return code: 
$($res.StatusCode) - $([int] $res.StatusCode))`n" -ForegroundColor red
    }
} catch {
    write-host "`nSite $url is having some DNS issues`n" -ForegroundColor 
red
}
}
CheckForStatus $url
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Get-Content` cmdlet and pipe it for processing each line.

```
Get-Content "some_file" | % { CheckForStatus($_) }
```